# MySQL 8.0.30 Update Broke My Server

Tags: mysql

I have been running a database system for a few year using MySQL on Fedora. I kept up with regular updates, with both operating system and the MySQL server. It has been running smoothly for years. But, the latest update to MySQL 8.0.30 broke the system. After the update, the mysql service failed to start. The error log contains numerous lines such as:

```
2022-08-27T07:20:09.972994Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] Tablespace 'mysql' Page [page id: space=4294967294, page number=852] log sequence number 42688698848 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 42682823836.
2022-08-27T07:20:09.905480Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB redo log files. Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html for information about forcing recovery.
...
2022-08-27T07:20:10.009722Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2022-08-27T07:20:10.009741Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-08-27T07:20:11.394571Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.30) Source distribution.
```

Maybe the new version is incompatible with the mysql.ibd file of older (presumably 8.0.29 version)

Any way to get the system back up running, even rolling back the update?

The OS is Feroda 36. Almost all database is INNODB database.

I do have a backup of all important database files. Reinstalling and copying the old files over the new installation produced the same error message. I have also tried to set "innodb_force_recovery" and no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: File a bug report:  bugs.mysql.com